# Convert Win32 BITMAP into WinUI3 C++/WinRT ImageSource

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winui-3

I want to display files in a custom list view, I did all I needed besides displaying the icon for every file extension in the list view.

I found out how to take the HICON/BITMAP for the file extension, but I need to display it in the custom list view like an Image or something like that.

How can I achieve that?

I am working with WinUI3 C++/WinRT, up to date packages.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the question? What you've done now? What's the file type of the icon that you could get?

Comment: Are you using [`StorageFile::GetThumbnailAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync#windows-storage-storagefile-getthumbnailasync(windows-storage-fileproperties-thumbnailmode)) (or one of its overloads)?

Comment: [StorageFile::GetThumbnailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-storagefile-getthumbnailasync(windows-storage-fileproperties-thumbnailmode)) was all I needed, thank you, I will answer my own question later, maybe I could help others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that does that an `HBITMAP` => WinUI3 `Image.Source` conversion:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32")
#pragma comment(lib, "oleaut32")

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams; // for InMemoryRandomAccessStream
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Imaging; // for BitmapDecoder
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;  // for Image
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;  // for SoftwareBitmapSource

IAsyncAction SetImageSourceFromHBITMAPAsync(HBITMAP hBitmap, Image image)
{
  PICTDESC pd = {};
  pd.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof(PICTDESC);
  pd.picType = PICTYPE_BITMAP;
  pd.bmp.hbitmap = hBitmap;

  com_ptr<IPicture> picture;
  if (FAILED(OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pd, IID_IPicture, FALSE, (LPVOID*)picture.put()))) // #include <olectl.h> in pch.h
    return;

  InMemoryRandomAccessStream memStream; // #include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h> in pch.h
  com_ptr<IStream> stream;
  if (FAILED(CreateStreamOverRandomAccessStream(winrt::get_unknown(memStream), IID_PPV_ARGS(&stream)))) // #include <shcore.h> in pch.h
    return;

  if (FAILED(picture->SaveAsFile(stream.get(), TRUE, nullptr)))
    return;

  auto decoder = co_await BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(memStream); // #include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.h> in pch.h
  auto bitmap = co_await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode::Premultiplied);

  SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource; // #include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h> in pch.h
  co_await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(bitmap);
  image.Source(bitmapSource);
}
```

And an example on how to use it:

```
namespace winrt::WinUIApp1CPP::implementation
{
    MainWindow::MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        auto hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(nullptr, L"D:\\Downloads\\dog.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        if (!hBitmap)
            return;

        auto op{ SetImageSourceFromHBITMAPAsync(hBitmap, myImage()) }; // add this XAML somewhere <Image x:Name="myImage" />
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With the help of [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)'s comment I was able to find the answer for my own question, many thanks to him.

You will need these headers:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
```

This is the async method:

```
::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::ImageSource>
GetIconFromFile(
    const ::winrt::hstring& file,
    ::winrt::Windows::Storage::FileProperties::ThumbnailMode thumbnailMode = ::winrt::Windows::Storage::FileProperties::ThumbnailMode::DocumentsView
) {
    const auto& fileStorage = co_await ::winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(file);
    const auto& fileThumbnail = co_await fileStorage.GetThumbnailAsync(thumbnailMode);

    ::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage bitmapImage;
    bitmapImage.SetSource(fileThumbnail);

    co_return bitmapImage;
}
```

You can get rid of the namespaces by using them, but I decided not to do that because ambiguous errors could appear if you have things included from Windows namespace.

And you can use it like this:

```
// xaml
<Image x:Name="image" Width="40" Height="40"/>

//cpp
::winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction LoadImageIcon() {
        const auto& filePath = TEXT("<your file path>");
        image().Source(co_await GetIconFromFile(filePath));
    }
```

Comment: This is working. The above method does 2 things - 

1) For regular non-image files, it loads the file's icon (of associated app) like shown in Windows File Explorer 
2) For image files (jpg, png etc), it loads the thumbnail (small version of the image itself). Which affects the performance of my app.

I don't want the thumbnails to be loaded. I just want the file's icon so that the files list in my app loads faster.

Is there a way for this?